# Will rooting through Kingo brick the device?

Tags: rooting, samsung-knox, kingo

If you have Knox installed in your Samsung device and you try to root the device using the Kingo root app, will it brick your device?

Answer (score 0):

**Root**

Rooting won't brick your device unless you did it in the wrong way,

- Keep the battery full (greater than 75)
- Install appropriate drivers
- Make sure you use the official USB driver
- Follow the procedure.

**Kingo Root**

As per documentation

> Kingo Android Root has already rooted more than 100,000 devices, and we never met a bricking situation.

Refer to this [link.](http://www.kingoapp.com/faq.htm)